# html/css -- trying to center image and ignore body margins

Tags: ios, css, webkit, block, centering

Foo.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="testStyle.css" />
</head>
<body>
    The appearance of the text is good.  This image should be centered, but it isn't:
    <img class="centerblock" src="ice cream cone and dish.png" width="320" height="200"></img>
</body>
```

TestStyle.css:

```
body {margin-left:30px;}
body {margin-right:30px;}
.centerblock {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
.centerblock {
position:fixed;
top:10px;
left: 10px;
}
```

Maybe that can help, Although i don't know what can happen if you turn the phone.

I would make that main content area to fit to the edge of display and define all align properties for each element.

It's never very smart to do:

```
body {margin-left:30px;}
body {margin-right:30px;}
```

There is also option:

```
.main-container {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

That also centers all the content but i think, also would not solve your problem.